# Rails add pass variable to create new record from loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models Ticket and Table. Ticket belongs to Table.

I want to show an index of tables, each one should have a button to a new ticket with corresponding table assigned.

tickets controller:

```
  def new_from_table
    @ticket = Ticket.new(table_id: table_id)
  end
```

and in my view:

```
<% @tables.each do |table| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= table.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Add', new_from_table_path(:table_id => table.id), class: "btn btn-sm btn-success" %></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

and routes:

```
  get 'new_from_table', to: 'tickets#new_from_table', as: :new_from_table
```

But I can't figure out how to pass table.id on loop to ticket.table_id.

Solution above returns:

> undefined local variable or method `table_id' for Ticket......

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined local variable or method `table_id' for Ticket......

That means, while table_id is passed with path`new_from_table_path(:table_id => table.id)` at controller#action this parameter table_id will be taken dynamically as `params[:table_id]`

```
  def new_from_table
    @ticket = Ticket.new(table_id: params[:table_id])
  end
```